# Trying to sort column in alphabetical order in R, not accounting for lowercase letters

Tags: r, sorting

I'm aware that `df[order(df$name),]` will sort my column alphabetically, and this does work, however it is not accounting for characters that start with a lowercase letter. i.e Apple will be sorted but apple will not.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: df[order(df$name),] works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df[order(tolower(df$name)),]
```

should do the trick. `tolower` and `toupper` are generally useful whenever you have casing issues.